# MySQL Workbench Synchronization: error in CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`timestamps` (

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to MySQL. I tried creating a few tables in a new schema using MySQL Workbench. I attempted to "Synchronize Model with Database" but it completed with errors.  For some reason the MySQL Workbench auto generated SQL includes CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`timestamps`..... which appears to be the problem.  The closest thing I could find of relevance is in Workbench's schema GUI editor it has a pane on the right called Modeling Actions which had a default template called timestamps.  I didn't use it in my simple test project.

I am using MySQL 5.7.16 Win64.
MySQL Workbench: 6.3.7 (build 1199CE)

I do realize that it has something to do with a null value being put into a non-null field but, how is that table/field being created in the first place if it isn't part of my tables?

Can anyone please lead me in the right direction?  I came from Access as a novice and this system is very different.  I can't get the schema design to be synchronized with MySQL.

```
*****************************************************************************
* MySQL Workbench auto-generated SQL - it is being made during Synchronize...
*****************************************************************************

    -- MySQL Workbench Synchronization
    -- Generated: 2016-11-08 06:30
    -- Model: New Model
    -- Version: 1.0
    -- Project: Name of the project
    -- Author: Turtle

    SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`timestamps` (
      `create_time`  NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `update_time`  NULL)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tblWorkLog` (
      `UserName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `tblUsers_UserName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`UserName`),
      INDEX `fk_tblWorkLog_tblUsers_idx` (`tblUsers_UserName` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_tblWorkLog_tblUsers`
        FOREIGN KEY (`tblUsers_UserName`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`tblUsers` (`UserName`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tblUsers` (
      `UserName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `fName` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `mName` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `lName` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `tblUserscol` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `tblWorkLog_UserName` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`UserName`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tblJobCodes` (
      `JobCode` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `ShortName` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `LongName` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `Description` VARCHAR(4000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`JobCode`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tblRoles` (
      `RoleID` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      `Description` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`RoleID`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


    SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
    SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

--

```
*****************************************************************************
* Error message from MySQL Workbench
*****************************************************************************

    Executing SQL script in server
    ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `update_time`  NULL)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT C' at line 2
    SQL Code:
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`timestamps` (
              `create_time`  NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
              `update_time`  NULL)
            ENGINE = InnoDB
            DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
    SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed
    Fetching back view definitions in final form.
    Nothing to fetch
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating one table each time.

But I belive the problem is your using `NULL` with `default`

Check this **[examples](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp)**

Should be:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`timestamps` (
      `create_time`  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `update_time`)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```